# public float value can't be accessed in a function within the same derived class c# (using unity)

Tags: c#, variables, unity-game-engine, procedure, public

Here is my code:

```
public float moveSpeed = 2000;
public float rotateSpeed = 2000;

protected bool moving, rotating;

private Vector3 destination;
private Quaternion targetRotation;

// Game Engine methods, all can be overridden by subclass

//overides protected virtual methods in WorldObject
protected override void Awake(){
    base.Awake ();
}

protected override void Start () {
    base.Start();
    Debug.Log (moveSpeed + rotateSpeed);
}
```

And the result is 0 from the Debug.Log. I've checked and neither of them are initialized for some reason, not sure why?

Comment: could you add f as a suffix? something like this: public float moveSpeed = 2000f;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the values to int, do the same error occurs?

Comment: Thanks - that solves everything - I should of though of that :) Still it should still work with float but anyway - thanks

Comment: It´s pretty strange, I did a test on your code using floats and had no errors.